# How i can generate a unique ID every time in android even I re-install the application ?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am stuck in a problem. Actually I need unique transaction ID every time uploading record to server. The data for 1 record is large so i can't keep all records in DB table. I tried to keep the transaction Id's in a table and set auto increment but when i uninstall the application it start generating the id's from 1. I tried android global variables which are set in start of application and are only accessible within the app. I need to set a global variable in android which can be accessed even I uninstall my application and then install again. System property also didn't work for me. Any suggestions how i can generate a unique ID every time ?

Answer (score 3):

Generate a unique ID using this

```
public static String getImageUUID() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

Comment: uuid is pseudo random generation algo which does not promise uniqueness every time and used for randomization rather than uniqueness.

Comment: Its a 'Algorithms for Creating a Time-Based UUID' refer https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: what if i need in a sequence ?? like sequence property in oracle

Answer (score 0):

How about generating id with help of currentTimeMilliSeconds and mac Address;

```
WifiManager manager =(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String address = info.getMacAddress();

String id=System.currentMilliSeconds()+address;
```

This will be unique every time for any device.